# When using os.path.abspath() my computer outputs a relative path format instead of absolute format. Am I misunderstanding something?

Tags: python, os.path

I've tried searching for this issue for a while and haven't found the answer.

I've just learned about `os.path.abspath()` and `sys.argv` recently and was playing around with the commands. I realized when I use these commands the script outputs the path in relative format.

While just using `sys.argv[0]` it outputs the path in absolute format.

input:
`print(sys.argv[0])`
output:
`c:/Users/folder1/folder2/folder3/test.py`

Then when I try to print the absolute path of it again with `os.path.abspath()` I get this:

input:
`print(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])`
output:
`c:\Users\folder1\folder2\folder3\test.py`

It turned the absolute path into relative format. From the documentation I found the `os.path.abspath()` command should still output in absolute format, but in my case it doesn't. I searched for online examples that use the `.abspath()` command and all examples give outputs of paths in absolute format.
I've also tested `.dirname()` command and that also outputs the path name in relative format. What am I missing that is causing my script to do this? I run on Windows.

Thank you

Comment: I don't see any relative paths in your question: both examples seem to be outputting the identical absolute path, starting with `c:` and including a full directory path to the file `test.py`.

Comment: I suspect you don't understand what an absolute path is.  An absolute path is one that starts with "/" or, on WIndows, start with "X:/" where X is a drive letter.  On Windows, forward and backward slashes can be used interchangeably, except on the command line.

Comment: The duplicate's answers explain the differences between absolute and relative paths, even though the topic in the title is more narrow.